# Someone registered a domain through google, how can I redirect that url to another site?

Tags: google, redirects, domains

I need to be able to automatically redirect a URL that was registered with Google to another URL. No access to server or anything like that. Is there a way to do this with just messing with the DNS?

Comment: Can you explain this better. It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The Google help page says you can access your hosting account by clicking the "advanced DNS settings" link in the control panel.

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=53929

From that page:
"Google doesn't register or host domain names. We've partnered with a few companies that offer these services to make it easier to set up a Google Apps account."

This makes it sound like you can access hosting or registrar info from 3rd party sites which should give you what you need.

Hope this helps.